# Jquery function not loading after refreshing div using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, refresh

I have a several divs that a refreshed using Ajax after the user clicks on a link on the page.

Here's my code for the Ajax refresh div:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- AJAX CALL FOR MY PICTURES -->
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#pictures_wrapper a.delete_image').live('click', function(e){
     $('#pictures_wrapper').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' #pictures_wrapper' );     
     e.preventDefault(); 
}); 
});
</script>
```

On this same page, I am loading this Jquery effect:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- HOVER OVER ITEMS CHANGE BG COLOR -->
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".item_control_box").hide();
    jQuery('.each_item_container').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').show()
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

My issue is that when the user click on the link to refresh the Divs, this jquery effect breaks and no longer works. I'm thinking that I have to "reload" this function some how since only the div is being reloaded and not the whole page. How can I keep this Jquery function working after refreshing a div?

Comment: seems like you have to use `live` on `hover` event too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the callback function of the load, means u recall the jquery after loading has completed.

```
$('#pictures_wrapper').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' #pictures_wrapper', , function () { //hover effect function } );
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: hi, please refer to http://api.jquery.com/load/
The code here i just showing as your reference, I dint check for the syntax, but I solve similar situation by that :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work if you change your `.bind()` calls to `.live()`:

```
jQuery('.each_item_container').live('mouseenter', function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').show()
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').hide();
});
```

`.hover()` is the same thing as using `.bind('mouseover', function () {...})` and `.bind('mouseout', function () {...})`

When you want to bind event handlers to elements not yet in the DOM you can use `.live()` or `.delegate()`: http://api.jquery.com/live/, http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

> Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the future.

As of jQuery 1.7 you should be using `.on()` as `.bind()`, `.live()`, and `.delegate()` are depreciated: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I think this is the route I need to take, but when I updated my code, and I hover over the div, it doesn't show .item_control_box

Answer (score 1):

Better put the code in a custom function with a name

```
function effectLoad(){

$(".item_control_box").hide();
    jQuery('.each_item_container').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').show()
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').hide();
    });

}
```

then put the function in your ajax success function

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'your_php_file.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:formData,
            success: function(response)
            {

                $("#formbox").html(response);

                  effectLoad();

            }

        });
```

Hope it will work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as @Guillaume Cisco mentioned in the comments you have to rebind the hover effect to dynamically inserted elements in the DOM, you can do it like

```
$(".item_control_box").live(
{
mouseenter:function(){
jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').show();
},
mouseleave:function(){
jQuery(this).find('.item_control_box').hide();
}
});
```